# Bind a ICommand to a WPF tabcontrol/tabitem using XAML (MVVM)

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF 3.5 app built using MVVM pattern. I have a tabcontrol and I want to excecute an ICommand on the view model when the user clicks a certain tab (jn my case the "Preview" tab).
How do I hook up my ICommand to the tabitem or tabcontrol using just the XAML? I am using MVVM so I dont want to use events and get *filthy, dirty* code in the code-behind.

I think Im missing  something simple here!
Thanks,P

Answer (score 2):

You should use InvokeCommandAction, Looks like this:

```
        <TabItem Header="TabItem">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="SomeCommand"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <Grid />
        </TabItem>
```

Be sure to include the xmlns in the top:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
```

and of course to reference `System.Windows.Interactivity` (new in WPF4)

Comment: you can do it in WPF3.5 as well, only u'll have to use blend SDK (google it). Due note that I'm using `behaviors` here, that although are a new feature in WPF4, are basically available since WPF3 - it's just an Attached Property trick.

Comment: hmm. tried that. but cant get past this beauty: "XamlParseException: Cannot add content of type 'System.Windows.Interactivity.EventTrigger' to an object of type 'System.Windows.Interactivity.TriggerCollection'."

Comment: did u make sure to include system.windows.interactivity of WPF 3.5?