# WPF-MVVM: TabItem Header click event handling in viewmodel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I found out alot of answers about handling TabItem header click event in the code behind but i need to handle that event in the View Model.
Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162805/bind-a-icommand-to-a-wpf-tabcontrol-tabitem-using-xaml-mvvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bind a Property to the Tab Control SelectedIndex.

**Your XAML:**

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" SelectedIndex="{Binding tabControlSelectedIndex}">
```

**Your ViewModel:**

```vb
Private _tabControlSelectedIndex As Integer
Public Property tabControlSelectedIndex As Integer
    Get
        Return _tabControlSelectedIndex
    End Get
    Set(value As Integer)
        If _tabControlSelectedIndex <> value Then
            _tabControlSelectedIndex = value
             OnPropertyChanged("tabControlSelectedIndex")

             '
             ' Whatever you want to handle here
             '

        End If
    End Set
End Property
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use MVVM light's `EventToCommand` approach:

1. Add a reference to `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` to your project.
2. Add `xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"`
3. Add xaml e.g.:

   `<Button>
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
           <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter" >
               <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding FooCommand}" />
           </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
   </Button>`

You can see the code here:
http://www.danharman.net/2011/08/05/binding-wpf-events-to-mvvm-viewmodel-commands/